# Scraping Google search using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, search, beautifulsoup, scrape

I wanted to scrape multiple pages of Google search.
Till now I could manage to scrape only the first page, but how could I do it for multiple pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import re
from collections import Counter

def search(query):
    url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+query

    text = []
    final_text = []

    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")

    for desc in soup.find_all("span",{"class":"st"}):
        text.append(desc.text)

    for title in soup.find_all("h3",attrs={"class":"r"}):
        text.append(title.text)

    for string in text:
        string  = re.sub("[^A-Za-z ]","",string)
        final_text.append(string)

    count_text = ' '.join(final_text)
    res = Counter(count_text.split())

    keyword_Count = dict(sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))

    for x,y in keyword_Count.items():
        print(x ," : ",y)


search("girl")
```

Comment: Scrape for the link that points to the next page, `request.get(href_for_next_page)` rinse and repeat.

Comment: I would recommend reading the book, Web Scraping with Python. I'm sure that you can find a pdf somewhere on the web but I would also buy it. Page 68 has good info about this very topic. However, you should place your code in a loop with limits on how many times it will run, otherwise you'll be running an endless code and taxing the resources of the servers.

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish in case of Google you have to put limit not because it will crash the server, but if you do endless requests Google simple blocks your IP for couple of hours.

Comment: Yeah I should have clarified that point. Most sites will blacklist you.

Answer (score 3):

```
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "&start=" + str((page - 1) * 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

like comment above you need next page URL and put the code inside loop

```
def search(query):
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + query
    while url:
        text = []
        ....
        ....
        for x,y in keyword_Count.items():
            print(x ," : ",y)

        # get next page url
        url = soup.find('a', id='pnnext')
        if url:
            url = 'https://www.google.com/' + url['href']
        else:
            print('no next page, loop ended')
            break
```

To make `soup.find('a', id='pnnext')` work you may need to set user-agent for requests

Answer (score 0):

Code below does actual pagination through the "Next" button link.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib.parse
import lxml

def print_extracted_data_from_url(url):

    headers = {
        "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

    print(f'Current page: {int(soup.select_one(".YyVfkd").text)}')
    print(f'Current URL: {url}')
    print()

    for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
        head_text = container.find('h3', class_='LC20lb DKV0Md').text
        head_sum = container.find('div', class_='IsZvec').text
        head_link = container.a['href']
        print(head_text)
        print(head_sum)
        print(head_link)
        print()

    return soup.select_one('a#pnnext')


def scrape():
    next_page_node = print_extracted_data_from_url(
        'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola')

    while next_page_node is not None:
        next_page_url = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.google.com', next_page_node['href'])

        next_page_node = print_extracted_data_from_url(next_page_url)

scrape()
```

Part of the output:

```
Results via beautifulsoup

Current page: 1
Current URL: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola

The Coca-Cola Company: Refresh the World. Make a Difference
We are here to refresh the world and make a difference. Learn more about the Coca-Cola Company, our brands, and how we strive to do business the right way.‎Careers · ‎Contact Us · ‎Jobs at Coca-Cola · ‎Our Company
https://www.coca-colacompany.com/home

Coca-Cola
2021 The Coca-Cola Company, all rights reserved. COCA-COLA®, "TASTE THE FEELING", and the Contour Bottle are trademarks of The Coca-Cola Company.
https://www.coca-cola.com/
```

---

Alternatively, you can do this using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

def scrape():
  
  params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "coca cola",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  }

  search = GoogleSearch(params)
  results = search.get_dict()

  print(f"Current page: {results['serpapi_pagination']['current']}")

  for result in results["organic_results"]:
      print(f"Title: {result['title']}\nLink: {result['link']}\n")

  while 'next' in results['serpapi_pagination']:
      search.params_dict["start"] = results['serpapi_pagination']['current'] * 10
      results = search.get_dict()

      print(f"Current page: {results['serpapi_pagination']['current']}")

      for result in results["organic_results"]:
          print(f"Title: {result['title']}\nLink: {result['link']}\n")

scrape()
```

Part of the output:

```
Results from SerpApi

Current page: 1
Current URL: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola

The Coca-Cola Company: Refresh the World. Make a Difference
We are here to refresh the world and make a difference. Learn more about the Coca-Cola Company, our brands, and how we strive to do business the right way.‎Careers · ‎Contact Us · ‎Jobs at Coca-Cola · ‎Our Company
https://www.coca-colacompany.com/home

Coca-Cola
2021 The Coca-Cola Company, all rights reserved. COCA-COLA®, "TASTE THE FEELING", and the Contour Bottle are trademarks of The Coca-Cola Company.
https://www.coca-cola.com/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.