# How to scrape multiple pages of a site using paging using BeautifulSoup and requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pagination

I created a scraper using BeautifulSoup and requests that scrapes the search results of the site [Ask.com](https://Ask.com) based on the keywords entered by the user. For now this scraper is limited to only one page of scraped search results.  Here is the basic code of my scraper:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST['search']
        url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?q='+search
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')

        result_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'PartialSearchResults-item'})

        final_result = []

        for result in result_listings:
            result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
            result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
            result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text

           
            final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc))

        context = {
            'final_result': final_result
        }
```

And I would like to make sure that BeautifulSoup can scrape the other 5 pages of search results by following the pagination, I modified my code like this:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST['search']
        url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?q='+search
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')
       

        result_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'PartialSearchResults-item'})

        final_result = []

        for result in result_listings:
            while True:
                result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
                result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
                result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text

                result_nextpage = result.find('a').get('PartialWebPagination-next')
                if result_nextpage.find_all('div', {'class': 'PartialSearchResults-item'}):
                    url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?q='+ search + result.find('a').get('PartialWebPagination-next')
                    return url
                else :
                    final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc))


           
                

        context = {
            'final_result': final_result
        }
```

After when I run `python manage.py runserver` in order to run my server and when I enter the keywords to search in the appropriate search bar, instead of sending me the scraping results the page keeps loading without stopping. I therefore ask for help from more experienced members of the community because I do not know where my error lies. inspired by this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324849/scraping-google-search-using-beautifulsoup)  I modified the url variable as well:

```
url = "https://www.ask.com/search?q=" + search+ "&start=" + str((page - 1) * 5)
```

and when I executed, I obtained the following error  **name 'page' is not defined**  . So I ask for the help of the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page is working for single page then with a little change it will work  on next pages also. Just try to change page number in the url as `ask.com` supports it.

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST['search']
        max_pages_to_scrap = 5
        final_result = []
        for page_num in range(1, max_pages_to_scrap+1):
            url = "https://www.ask.com/web?q=" + search + "&qo=pagination&page=" + str(page_num)
            res = requests.get(url)
            soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')
            result_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'PartialSearchResults-item'})

            for result in result_listings:
                result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
                result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
                result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text
           
                final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc))

        context = {'final_result': final_result}
```